# How to fix error "VC Libraries QFE Patch does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your system"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I install VS90SP1-KB974479-x86.exe to update VS2008 t0 VS2008 SP1, however I received error:

> VC Libraries QFE Patch does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your system. Please click the link below for more details

Comment: Have you searched for this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you use intranet for office, Change the network to online and download the update file VS90sp1-KB945140-KOR.exe.

This file size is 551kb.

The link is that https://www.microsoft.com/ko-kr/download/details.aspx?id=10986